# SwiftUI, Sheets, and getting called multiple times

Tags: swiftui

EDIT: Got by this by moving out the time consuming logic out so it's only run once. Thanks for the help. Leaving the question up in case it helps anyone else.

I'm working on a SwiftUI Multiplatform app. I have a button that, when pressed, opens a sheet. One variable passed in is a method that generates an array for the contents of that sheet.

I find when I press the button the contents are generated three times. It's not apparent in iOS but in macOS when I close the sheet the other two instances shows up back to back momentarily (creating a sheet flickering appearance). I can't figure out why it's run three times.

I simplified my code down for an example which now, when pressed, runs two instead of three times. Is there any way to only generate the content and view once?

Code Example:

Content View
import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
private enum Destinations {
    case empty
}
@State private var selection: Destinations?

@State private var showSheet = false

var body: some View {
    
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                    Section(content: {
                        Button(action: {
                            showSheet = true
                        }, label: {
                            Label {
                                Text("Generate and Open")
                            } icon: {
                                Image(systemName: "doc.plaintext")
                            }
                        })
                    }, header: {
                        Text("This Section")
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                        SheetView(showQuiz: $showSheet, questionSTr: generateValueToPassIn())
                            .onAppear(){
                                print("in on appear sheet")
                            }
                    }
                
            } // List End
            .navigationTitle("Quiz")
#if os(iOS)
            .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
#endif
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                switch selection ?? .empty {
                case .empty: Text("Please select an option to continue.")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    private func generateValueToPassIn() -> String {
        print("In here; should be once")
        return "this string"
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

Sheet View being called:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SheetView: View {
// The variable that are used here and in the parent view
@Binding var showQuiz: Bool

@State var questionSTr: String

init(showQuiz: Binding<Bool>, questionSTr: String) {
    print("In sheet INIT")
    _showQuiz = showQuiz
    self.questionSTr = questionSTr
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        Text(questionSTr)
        Button() {
            showQuiz = false
        } label: {
            Text("Exit Quiz")
        }
    }
}
}

struct SheetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    SheetView(showQuiz: .constant(true), questionSTr: "test")
}
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: try to move the `.sheet` out of the `NavigationSplitView`

Comment: Didn't seem to help my main project. And my demo project is called several time the first time then only once each subsequent time

Comment: moving the `.sheet(...)` outside the `NavigationSplitView` works well for me. On MacOS 13.3, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems. Note, there is no need for the `init(showQuiz: Binding<Bool>, questionSTr: String){...}`
 you can just remove it.

Comment: I've seen a bunch of questions in this vein. The main issue here is that, somewhat counter-intuitively, the structures underlying the Views are being initialized many times during the life of the app. Any data you need to be consistent should be stored outside there structures (say, using `@State` wrappers). For instance, you can add a new `@State` variable for holding the question, generate the question when the button is pressed and pass that value to the sheet. You can even make that value optional and use it instead of `$showSheet` to toggle the sheet.

Comment: I used to do something like that @Baglan but when I create an optional variable and set it on the button it isn't seen on the sheet call. When the view is created the first time it crashes. I got around here by moving the string creation to the onAppears of the secondary view.

Comment: @Kyra here's a sample illustrating how it could work: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/b0cd5b5dc7c0699c2dbb889c80b319d8

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Baglan. Works perfect in my minimal example.